# iOS NSDictionary value determine if Boolean from JSON boolean

Tags: ios, json, sbjson

I have a JSON response from a web server that looks like this:

```
{"success":true, "token":"123456"}
```

and I want to use that in an if statement, and compare it with "YES".

However, doing this doesn't work:

```
NSDictionary *response = [response JSONValue]; // the JSON value from webservice response, converted to NSDictionary

if ([response objectForKey:@"success"]){} // does not work
if ([response objectForKey:@"success"] == YES){} // does not work
if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue] == YES) {} // does not work...erroneous probably
```

How can I work around this? Typecasting in Boolean yields a warning too

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON response?

Comment: the question was tagged sbjson. I am using the ios library SBJSON http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Comment: I forgot to highlight the code that does the parsing, sorry

Answer (score 61, accepted):

since `[response objectForKey:@"success"]` does not work, what happens when you try `[response valueForKey: @"success"]`?

I suspect it returns a NSNumber and then you can do something like:

```
NSNumber * isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber *)[response objectForKey: @"success"];
if([isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES)
{
    // this is the YES case
} else {
    // we end up here in the NO case **OR** if isSuccessNumber is nil
}
```

Also, what does `NSLog( @"response dictionary is %@", response );` look like in your Console?  I see the JSON library you're using [does return NSNumber types for `objectForKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714746/complex-json-parsing-using-objective-c), so I suspect you might not have a valid NSDictionary.

Comment: You're missing the `@` symbol before the first argument of `NSLog`

Comment: You may want to actually test the type instead of doing a simple cast, or put this code in a try/catch block.  Otherwise, if the JSON changes, you may accidentally send `boolValue` to an NSString (which will return `YES` for "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a digit 1-9), or a collection object, which will throw an exception.

Comment: this solution is not effective and is long. the short answer is if([response objectForKey: @"success"] boolValue])

Answer (score 11):

An alternative approach to this, which requires no conversion to NSNumber is something like below:

```
if ([response objectForKey:@"success"])
{
    if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue])
        NSLog(@"value is true");
}
```